# Why NDEBUG instead of RELEASE?

Tags: c, assert, c-preprocessor

The standard C assert macro is disabled when the macro `NDEBUG` is defined, meaning "Not debug". This leads to really awful double negative cases like `#ifndef NDEBUG //DebuggingCode #endif`. It seems like RELEASE would have been a better choice of terms, but I can't believe the standards committee would have done it that way without some reason to do so....

Comment: I find it very easy to switch between DEBUG and NDEBUG.

Comment: `NDEBUG` simply implies *no debug*. `RELEASE` might imply more.

Comment: "Debug" / "not debug" has some meaning for pretty much all programming environments. "Release" / "releasing software" / "making a release" is completely different conversation that happens a long time after you've chosen compiler flags.

Comment: `#if defined(RELEASE)` `#define NDEBUG` `#else` `#undef NDEBUG` `#endif`

Comment: @pmg: Yes, I can do such things myself. I'm not complaining about the state of things as they are; I'm trying to figure out why the decision was made so that I can learn things (e.g. if I should reuse similar tactics in my own compile flags or something)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having a macro RELEASE implies that the code is ready for distribution - when it may not. NDEBUG on the other hand implies that debugging is complete, hence ready for testing.

I also suppose that having to turn things off is better than having to make sure that you have turned everything on. That is why most OSs (for example) have most things switched on when a lot of people do not need it.

Just my humble thoughts.

Answer (score 7):

The macro `NDEBUG` controls how `assert` behave.

You should typically NOT use it for anything else. If you would use it for other things, like extra debug trace output, you don't have the option to build your application without this extra code but with assertions enabled.

I would recommend that you define your own preprocessor symbol, say MY_TRACE, and use it. Also, define it to `0` or `1` and use `#if MY_TRACE`. That way you could catch files using the symbol without being properly initialized, if you configure your compiler to issue a warning when using an uninitialized variable in a preprocessor expression.

Comment: Why should I not use it for anything else?

Comment: Well, if you don't use it for anything else but controlling `assert`, you would never need to write `#ifndef NDEBUG`.

Comment: What happens when you need to leave `assert`s enabled to track down a rare hard-to-reproduce bug, but don't want thousands of lines of debug output being spewed all over the place?

Comment: Why is it not `NASSERT` then...? `NDEBUG` says to me "no debug". IMHO `NDEBUG` should cover all debug output you have in your application. Then you can possibly use extra macros if you want to **turn on** somethig special. Defining "1000" non-standard macros to get rid off custom debug levels does not look convenient...

Answer (score 3):

> I can't believe the standards committee would have [chosen to use the name NDEBUG to control `assert()`] without some reason to do so....

I can only guess, but I suspect that pre-standard there may have been several different names used by various implementations to control how assert macros worked, and the committee possibly decided to chose a 'neutral' name that was somewhat unlikely to be be used in existing code for some unrelated reason. I think it might have been rather common for `RELEASE` to be used as a macro in a fair bit of code, so using that name (or `DEBUG`) to control the `assert()` macro might lead to conflicts (particularly for users who might want fine control of assertions, turning them on only for portions of code).

Answer (score 0):

As long term Eiffel user i can tell you that it is used in a different way then debug/nodebug. As pointed out the only effect is to disable the assert statements. The purpose of assert is to add pre- and postcondition checks. Using it heavily is recommended, and it can slow down the performance of your program by factor 10 or more. This is called (Poor Men's) Design By Contract.

When using NDEBUG it does not really mean you are finished with debugging, just that it this heavy debugging instrumentation is removed.

The popular Debug/Release is unfortunately not a best case in practical development where you have infact an Alpha, Beta, Release release model for good reasons.

In alpha software is so buggy that you compile it without NDEBUG and debugger symbols. Beta is compiled with NDEBUG set and debugger symbols (and maybe already with optimization switches) and the final release is then compiled with NDEBUG and full optimization.